# Angular6 HTML Input-Field with changing Dropdown Options

Tags: html, angular

I want to implement an HTML5 Input field which supports the user with his input.

Imagine the case that the user has to enter not just random text, he has to follow a specific grammar:

```
rule: <expression> {<op><expression>}
expression: <Object>[<property>] is <State>
property: key=value
State: active | inactive | valid .....
```

I thought about a state machine like if the user enters this then the user is in state 2 and if not he is in state 3 and so on.

I found the following:

```
<input list="browsers">

<datalist id="browsers">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

And it is nearly what I need. But as you can see it is a little bit too static. I want to update the options and they should appear at any time not just for the first selection.

So if the user starts a new expression then options change then they change again after he did some input. The options should be clickable and the value of the options should be added to the previous text.

I thought about a solution where I add just a  tag below the input field where I change the innerHtml but this seems not to be a good solution, what is a better idea?

Comment: Or the dropdown should not be shown at any time. It should be shown when the focus is on the input field.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more exactly what it is you're trying to do? What do you mean by previous text?

Comment: Previous text: Server[secure=true] is active and
--> now here is the dropdown with options where the user can choose one
New Text: Server[secure=true] is active and Connection[bidirectional=true]

Connection[bidirectional=true] was the chosen option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself with the code below:

component.ts:

```
export class Component {
  ruleInputFocused:boolean = false;
  selectActive: boolean=false;
  options: string[]; 

  constructor() {
    this.setState(0);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  changeSelective(value:boolean){
    this.selectActive= value;
  }

  changeFocused(value:boolean){
    if(this.selectActive == false){
      this.ruleInputFocused = value;
    }
  }


  setState(stateNumber: number){
    this.options = [];
    this.positionCounter = -1;

    if(stateNumber == 0){
      this.options.push("(");
      this.options.push("Object[key=value] ");
    }
  }

  optionClicked(i){
    this.ruleText = this.ruleText.concat(this.options[i]);
    document.getElementById("ruleInput").focus();
  }




  positionCounter = -1; 

  @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
  public handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    if(this.ruleInputFocused){
        if(event.key == 'ArrowDown'){
          this.positionCounter++;
          if(this.positionCounter>this.options.length -1){
            this.positionCounter = 0;
          }
          console.log(this.positionCounter);
        }else if(event.key == 'ArrowUp'){
          this.positionCounter--;
          if(this.positionCounter<0){
            this.positionCounter = this.options.length -1
          }
        }else if(event.key == 'Enter'){
          if(this.positionCounter != -1){
            this.optionClicked(this.positionCounter);
          }
        }
    }
  }

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="mainContainer">


  <div class="ruleInputDiv">
        <div class="divLabel">Rule: </div>
        <input id="ruleInput" type="text"  autocorrect="off" 
          (focus)="changeFocused(true)" (focusout)="changeFocused(false)" [(ngModel)]="ruleText" >
        <button id="ruleInputCheckButton" (click)="checkRule()">Check</button>

  </div>
  <!--[hidden]=!ruleInputFocused-->
  <div class="optionsDiv" id="optionsDiv" [hidden]="!ruleInputFocused">
      <div class="singleOption" *ngFor="let option of options; let i = index" 
        [ngClass]="{selected: positionCounter===i}" (click)="optionClicked(i)" (mouseenter) ="changeSelective(true)" (mouseleave) ="changeSelective(false)">
          {{option}}
          <div class="verticalBorderDiv"></div>
      </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

CSS: